# i can run my flutter app in chrome but i can't run in android device and emulator

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\starwin\myapp_flutter\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,474ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried but I can't fix it

Comment: Check your build.gradle file line number 24

Comment: check your gradle or publish it here !